# How to copy EXACT value from UltraGrid cell to Excel

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics's UltraGrid widget to create Excel-like grid. I am trying to copy value from cell and paste it to Excel. That works fine, except for one minor issue: it copies value that is shown in the cell (`Text` property), instead of real value contained in the cell (`Value` property). Is there an option to copy real value, instead of shown value?

I've tried using

```
PerformAction(UltraGridAction.Copy, false, false);
```

and looking for some method or way to copy real values, but haven't found none. I've also tried to implement my own copy function, but this creates CSV data, and doesn't copy actual cells.

```
void OnExportToClipboardSelectedRows(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<UltraGridRow> rows = this.Grid.GetAllSelectedRows().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(rows[0].Cells.Count);

        List<string> newRows = new List<string>();
        if (rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int minRowIndex = -1;
            int maxRowIndex = -1;

            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                if (row.Index < minRowIndex || minRowIndex == -1)
                    minRowIndex = row.Index;
                if (row.Index > maxRowIndex || maxRowIndex == -1)
                    maxRowIndex = row.Index;
            }

            List<int> selectedCols = new List<int>();
            foreach (var cell in this.Grid.Selected.Cells)
            {
                if (!selectedCols.Contains(cell.Column.Index))
                    selectedCols.Add(cell.Column.Index);
            }

            for (int i = minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex; i++)
            {
                List<string> cells = new List<string>();
                foreach (int j in selectedCols)
                {
                    cells.Add(this.Grid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                }
                newRows.Add(String.Join("\t", cells));
            }
            Clipboard.SetText(String.Join("\n", newRows));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No selected rows found.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So if the cell is a formula, you want to copy that and not the answer to the equation?

Comment: What is the difference between the Cell Text property and the Value property?

Comment: @krillgar Actually, this problem doesn't involve formulas. I have decimal value (ie. -623.456213), which is displayed as (623.456) in red color. I want real value: -623.456213. Currently, I get -623.456.

Comment: @Steve See my comment above. Real value is -623.456213, and it is stored in `Value` property, and display value (623.456) is stored in `Text` property.

Comment: What is wrong in your copy solution. It seems that you work with the Value property here, but of course, calling ToString on Value (an object type) could implicitly convert a decimal value to a string using the current locale settings (transforming the point in comma).

Comment: Wrong is that it copies only value (as CSV field) and not cell (with all it's properties).

Comment: Did you try to use the UltraGridExcelExport component. Usually this make a good job to export data to excel maintaining the appearance of the cells

Comment: I have other function that also exports data to excel. I asked specific question because I need to have ability to copy data.

Comment: So your requisite is to have that data in the Clipboard and then paste it into an existing Excel Worksheet?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I know there is no way to automatically copy all the cell properties in the clipboard and then automatically set Excel to the same format. As I have said you can use the infrastructure of UltraGridCellExporter and the Infragistics.Documents.Excel assembly to insert the selected grid cells inside a new or existing excel file and it is pretty easy to do.

Comment: Once you have the exported data in a separate (temporary) excel worksheet then you can probably use some specific excel library or Interop to select the block of cells from the temporary excel worksheet and copy it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exhaustive trial/error attempts I finally come to working solution:

```
var selectedCells = this.Grid.Selected.Cells;

// Loop through selected cells and put them in "edit mode" (actually, show plain text)
foreach (var cell in selectedCells)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cell.CellDisplayStyle);
    cell.CellDisplayStyle = CellDisplayStyle.PlainText;                
}

// Execute copy command
this.Grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.Copy, false, false);

// Loop through selected cells and bring them back to original state
foreach (var cell in selectedCells)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cell.CellDisplayStyle);
    cell.CellDisplayStyle = CellDisplayStyle.Default;
}
```

When `CellDisplayStyle` is set to `PlainText`, cell displays actual value, rather then formatted value. In that state, perform `Copy` and return cells to original state.